# HTML/JAVASCRIPT I have made a board for a Tic Tac Toe game. How can I get this JavaScript to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I've tried with this JavaScript code I've found on the net and modified a little a bit ( **it still worked with the original HTML but not with mine** ). Here is the link to the original code: [link](https://dev.to/bornasepic/pure-and-simple-tic-tac-toe-with-javascript-4pgn)

This is my modified JavaScript code:

```
let currentPlayer = "X";
let player = 1;

document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('click', handleCellClick));

function handleCellClick(clickedCellEvent) {
    const clickedCell = clickedCellEvent.target;
    
    if(clickedCell.innerHTML != "")
    { 
    alert("Click somewhere else!");
    handleCellClick();
    }
    
    handleCellPlayed(clickedCell);
}

function handleCellPlayed(clickedCell) {
    
    clickedCell.innerHTML = currentPlayer;
    
    player++;
    handlePlayerChange();
}

function handlePlayerChange() {
    
    if(player%2 == 1)
    {
        currentPlayer = "X";
    }
    if(player%2 == 0)
    {
        currentPlayer = "O";
    }
}
```

And this is the new, HTML made by me, I've gave the same `class="cell"` attribute to every DIV but still it doesn't works. :(

```
<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <section>
    <div class="board">
        <div class="column1">  
            <div class="cell" id="11"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="12"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="13"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="14"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="15"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <div class="cell" id="21"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="22"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="23"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="24"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="25"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column3">
            <div class="cell" id="31"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="32"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="33"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="34"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="35"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column4">
            <div class="cell" id="41"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="42">X</div>
            <div class="cell" id="43"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="44"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="45"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column5">
            <div class="cell" id="51"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="52"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="53">O</div>
            <div class="cell" id="54"></div>
            <div class="cell" id="55"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: you should move `<script src="script.js"></script>` before `</body>`

Comment: You are missing Css. Please use css from your reference link

Comment: Thanks, yes the <script src="script.js"></script> was the problem. :D I didn't included the CSS, I was pretty confident that it didn't cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like document.querySelectorAll('.cell') has nothing to select as you included the script to **early** in the html...

Try to put

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

after the end of the section-tag and it should work.

But IMHO: Try to figure out, **at which time** javascript is executed and **why** ;-)

Comment: The JavaScript waits for the user to click on a DIV with the class="cell" attribute, then it calls the handleCellClick function. I just didn't knew I have to put the link to the end. :D Was this what you meant by "Try to figure out, at which time javascript is executed and why ;-)" ? Thanks again.